# Examples of old tefillin parshiot

Tags: tefilin, provenance, safrus

I recently opened a pair of parshiot (Beit Yosef, first half of the 20th century) and I'm trying to identify where they were written. I am certain that if they date to around the bar mitzvah of their original owner, they were written around Lemberg, northern Poland, or Bavaria (likely Fürth). If they are post-war, it is likely that the sofer lived in Boro Park, where the original owner eventually settled.

Are there any online references which would show examples of old tefillin parshiot consistent with the era and likely geographic origin of these tefillin ?

Comment: Please upload pics here if you can!

Comment: There's some REALLY old pictures of tefillin content at the Dead Sea Scrolls' official site:   https://www.deadseascrolls.org.il/explore-the-archive   Go to "Browse by Content" and pick "Tefillin and Mezuzot" and then just "Tefillin".

Comment: @DoubleAA, I can try, but I won’t have access to them for a few days

Comment: @noach Im not going anywhere!

Comment: Nice new profile picture.